# Will setting about 50 AlarmManagers at once have a negative effect on battery life?

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, notifications

So I need to send a notification with different content every day at the same time. We don't really have the resources to make them push, so they are queued locally like this:

```
for (date in allDateStrings) { //Formatted as MM/dd/yyyy, up to 50 values
    val sampleNotificationContent = "This notification is shown on $date"

    //WHEN
    val dateWithTimeFormatter = SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")
    val dateWithTime = dateWithTimeFormatter.parse("$date 07:00")
    val timeInMillisUntilNotifShouldDeliver = dateWithTime.time

    //REQUEST
    val notificationIntent = Intent("android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION")        
    notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT")
    notificationIntent.putExtra("body", sampleNotificationContent)
    notificationIntent.putExtra("requestCode", date.replace("/", "").toInt())

    //BROADCAST
    val broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    if (timeInMillisUntilNotifShouldDeliver > Calendar.getInstance().time.time) {
        val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillisUntilNotifShouldDeliver, broadcast)
    }
}
```

Up to 50 are queued at once, since we don't expect a large portion of users to actually open the app any more frequently than once every 50 days. The broadcasts are handled by a subclass of BroadcastReceiver and display successfully. Is there a better way to do this? I feel like I'm wasting a lot of battery with dozens of alarms being set at once. Do you think this would have a noticeable impact on performance or is it a non-issue?

Comment: Use firebase Messaging Service with timed schedule

Comment: That only supports one message body, right? Sorry, I clarified that the content needs to be different everyday.

Comment: You can send up to 15000 Messages per Minute each with up to 100 Receivers. If you want to have 1 Message create multiple Notifications you can use a Payload instead of a Message and create Notifications out of the given payload, but using 50 Alarmmanagers to make Notifications is a bad idea